# Trying to install letterbomb onto a SD card in ubuntu. Cannot find SD root dir?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, sd-card

When I plug my SD card in two file systems pop-up `boot` and `16gb file system`, both sub directories of `/media/` (which is a dir in ubuntu for periphials correct? not on the SD card itself). Following the directions here http://www.wiibrew.org/wiki/LetterBomb I am trying to move the boot.elf file into the `root` dir of the SD card. I have placed it in both `boot` and `16gb filesystem` to no avail.

I have formatted the SD card with GParted as a FAT32 system too.

Am I missing something? Where should boot.elf be place?

In the `boot` dir in the SD card there are a few other files. `start.elf start_cd.elf kernel.img bootcode.bin fixup.dat ...` Should they be there?

The `16gb file system` dir is empty (or was, I put the `private` dir there as is in the directions on the link above)

EDIT:

Here is a picture of how I have the files currently
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKwsq.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformat the card (after backing up anything you want on it, of course) using Disk Utility or similar. It appears that Letterbomb wants the card to have a single partition, not the multiple it has currently.

When freshly formatted as FAT, then move your `boot.elf` and `private` directories into the single folder that will appear.

Comment: Hmm, I've done that. If you're still willing to go deeper. The Wii I inserted it into has said "The SD card cannot be used". And now my computer will not recognize the SD card. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you pull it without syncing the writes maybe? could have corrupted it. Before removing the card, eject it.

Comment: I had completed the formatting and writing the files back, and used eject.

Comment: Windows recognized it, got it reformatted and rewritten files. Going to try again.